# Connect Tableau to GCP Compute Instance running TabPy

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, tableau-api, tabpy

I want to connect Tableau to TabPy installed on GCP Compute Instance. For that purpose I created a Compute Instance with default settings. Then I assigned a static external IP address to that instance.

In Tableau I am using an External Service Connection option:
[image]

In the Server field I am providing my GCP Compute Instance external IP address. I leave Port on the default option. With that setup Tableau is not able to create a connection. Does someone know what I should change/add in the instance configuration to successfully create that connection?

I think I should be using Username and Password option, but I am not quite sure how to get username and password to my newly created GCP Compute Instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access your VM from the internet on port 9004, you'd need to:

1. Create a new firewall rule allowing incoming traffic on 9004 with a tag.
2. Assign your instance with above tag.

See [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) and/or [short YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTVV9YzGw5k&t=32s)